# Format multi dimensional array using Laravel collections

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, laravel-collection

I have an array like this , which I am getting as a result of a database query (Google BigQuery) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [points] => 95
            [user] => 434
            [type] => 20
            [identifier] => tv
            [date] => 2016-11-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [points] => 349
            [id] => 2989631
            [type] => 20
            [identifier] => app
            [date] => 2016-11-01
        )
)
```

and another one for identifiers :

```
Array
(
    [tv] => 1
    [app] => 2
)
```

What I need is to do is to transform the array as the identifier key has corresponding value from identifiers array. So it will look like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [points] => 95
            [user] => 434
            [type] => 20
            [identifier] => 1
            [date] => 2016-11-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [points] => 349
            [id] => 2989631
            [type] => 20
            [identifier] => 2
            [date] => 2016-11-01
        )
)
```

How can I do this using Laravel collections ?

I have been trying with transform function, but not getting an idea to return specific column from the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```php
$identifiers = [
    'tv' => 1,
    'app' => 2
];

$result = array_map(function($item) use ($identifiers) {
    $item['identifier'] = $identifiers[$item['identifier']];
    return $item;
}, $itemsArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution here would be using an [acessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```
public function getIdentifier($value)
{
    return $identifiersArray[$value];
}
```

If you do this, you will not need to rebuild your collection.

Comment: One thing is I am using Google Bigquery as the database and so using their API to execute query. They are basically returning an array.